# java.lang.nullpointer exception in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a schedule which takes inputs from the user using the `Scanner` class. The point of the program is to print out the schedule. In the for loop in the `makeSchedule` function, there appears a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at this line:

```
System.out.print(blocks[numberSchedule[i][k] - 1] + "\t");
```

I tested this line of code outside of the function and it worked perfectly without any exceptions.

I do not know what I am missing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Schedule
{
  public int[][] scheduleArray;
  public static String A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;
  public static String[] blocks;

  public static void main(String[] args)

  {
    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] scheduleArray = new int[][] { {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2},
        {3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 8, 6},
        {8, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 5, 7}, {6, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5}};

    System.out.print("What is your A block class?");
    String A = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("What is your B block class?");
    String B = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("What is your C block class?");
    String C = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("What is your D block class?");
    String D = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("What is your E block class?");
    String E = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("What is your F block class?");
    String F = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("What is your G block class?");
    String G = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("What is your H block class?");
    String H = kboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    final String[] blocks = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H};

    makeSchedule(scheduleArray);

  }

  public static void makeSchedule(int[][] numberSchedule)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
      {
        if (k != 7)
        {
          System.out.print(blocks[numberSchedule[i][k] - 1] + "\t");
        }
        if (k == 7)
        {
          System.out.println(blocks[numberSchedule[i][k] - 1] + "\n");  
        }

      }

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Never do sth like this `k < 8`, use length attribute!

Comment: Please spend some time to learn how to use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - In this example, debugger would not be necessary. Btw, I got -1 for telling him to intialize blocks array, but nothing happened to the others.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `final String[]` of `final String[] blocks = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H};` because you declare a new variable in the current scope and your static field is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `public static String[] blocks;` of your class, only `final String[] blocks = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H};` of your main method.